# Images covering the texts in responsive screen using Bootstrap 5.1.3

Tags: html, css

Screenshot showing that the images covering the texts:

[image: Screenshot showing that the images covering the texts]

Code:

```css
.project-1, .project-2, .project-3, .project-4{
margin: 5% 7%;
height: 400px;
}

.unilever-project, .instagram-pic, .cork-airport-project,.instagram-page-cooking {
  width: 60%;
  height: 330px;
}
.text{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="projects">

<div class=" row project-1">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img src="images/Unilever.png" alt="unilever-project" class="bg-dark unilever-project">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 text">
    <h3>Unilever Internship Competition</h3>
    <p>I was asked to build a business purpose plan for one of their chosen products to promote their substainability and sales. I picked Hellmann's and built an integrated marketing campaign about food education for chilren in Ireland. Even
      though I only made it to the final, I enjoyed the whole experience and learnt a lot.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="project-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 ">

      <img src="images/instagram-PI.jpg" alt="instagram-pic" class=" bg-dark instagram-pic">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 text ">
      <h3>Instagram Innovation for Parternship International</h3>
      <p>I was doing an internship at PI and I wanted to do an innovation to improve the channel. I formed a strategy by changing the layout, creating contents, stories, videos, hashtags, paid advertising and so on. We successfully increased the
        number of followers by 5000 after 4 months. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="project-3">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6 ">


      <img src="images/Cork airport.jpg" alt="cork-airport-project" class="bg-dark cork-airport-project">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 text">
      <h3>Cork Airport Social Media Campaign</h3>
      <p>The Airport aimed to market share of 4% year on year and 2 share points by the end of the year through a social and digital campaign. My group in college created a FaceBook and Instagram campaigns called Everywhere from Home. The
        campaign would be promoted by micro-influencers who would live stream their journeys to different destination departuring from Cork Airport. Also, there would be online competition to encourage travel to the selected destinations. We got
        a great mark for the project. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="project-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-6">
      <img src="images/cookingpage.png" alt="instagram-page-cooking" class="bg-dark instagram-page-cooking">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 text">
      <h3>My own Instagram - Kokoseatingworld</h3>
      <p>Kokoseatingworld is where I share my passion about food and photography.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

On the large screen, it is working fine, but on medium and small screen it is not working properly.enter code here

I am new and I have only started one month ago. What can I do for this?

Are there other ways to do this? I am using Bootstrap 5.1.3

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and I looks fine to me.
Instead of the pics you're using I added a background color so I can see what's going on.
Honestly I experienced a few glitches while working with Bootstrap and Vscode that were resolved once I hit restart.

This is what I got when I tried your code:

[image: Screenshoot of Chrome dev view]

Your code + background colors:

```
   <style>
        .project-1, .project-2, .project-3, .project-4{
margin: 5% 7%;
height: 400px;
}

.unilever-project, .instagram-pic, .cork-airport-project,.instagram-page-cooking {
  width: 60%;
  height: 330px;
}
.text{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
    </style>
<div class="projects">

    <div class=" row project-1">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img src="images/Unilever.png" alt="unilever-project" class=" bg-dark unilever-project">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 text">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="project-2 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                <img src="images/instagram-PI.jpg" alt="instagram-pic" class=" bg-warning instagram-pic">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 text">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="project-3">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6">


                <img src="images/Cork airport.jpg" alt="cork-airport-project" class="bg-primary cork-airport-project">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 text">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="project-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-lg-6">
                <img src="images/cookingpage.png" alt="instagram-page-cooking" class="bg-danger instagram-page-cooking">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 text">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi G6ix, Thank you so much for your comment. I did restart everything but still the same problem. I guess maybe the text I posted up there was very short compared to my actual text. I guess that might be the reason why you did not see the images over the texts. When I turned on toggle pesticide, I can see the divs of img are on the divs of texts.

Comment: @Khoango1011 if you can share the code with the text you're working with, I can try to help.

Comment: I have updated the code above. Please have a look

Comment: I posted a new solution. I'm no bootstrap expert but from my experience I find it easier sticking to the bootstrap system instead of trying to add vanilla css on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the height css, it will fix the issue.

here:

```
    .project-1, .project-2, .project-3, .project-4{
margin: 5% 7%;

}
```